# How can I automatically delete another row from a join table when I delete a row?

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, sql-delete

I'm modelling a relationship between one or more rows in the table `Document` through a straightforward join table `RelatedDocuments`:

```
-----------
|from| to |
-----------
|   1|   2|
|   1|   5|
|   7|   1|
-----------
```

However, because these relationships are essentially bidirectional for my use case (and, given that, for ease of access through JPA) I added a trigger that "mirrors" each relation between from and two upon insert.

```
-----------
|from| to |
-----------
|   1|   2|
|   2|   1|
|   1|   5|
|   5|   1|
|   7|   1|
|   1|   7|
-----------
```

This allows me to easily find all `Document`s related to e.g. ID 1. However, I am unable to implement a corresponding delete trigger ("delete the opposite of what you just deleted") because of an

```
ORA-04091: table RELATEDDOCUMENTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

, indicating, quite correctly, that I'm trying to manipulate the table that triggered the trigger. Is there a good way around this? Particularly wrp/ to me wanting to leveraging plain JPA?

Comment: Would `DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE FROM = 1 OR TO = 1` work as intended? Then perhaps you wouldn't need the trigger.

Comment: Yes, I could write a native query like that. But I'd like to stay within the JPA Java object mappings, if possible. That is, I'd like to do ``document1.getRelatedDocuments().remove(document5);``, which would automatically be translated to a DELETE on the ``from=1,to=5`` row but not the opposite. That's what I would like the trigger to take care of.

Comment: Inside every complex object-relational mapping framework is a simple SQL statement struggling to be free.

Comment: Square peg, meet hammer :-)

Comment: I mean, it's really convenient most of the time (I've written enough JDBC to compare it to), but it's also always an oversimplification. Rock. Hard place. It's gotten better with JPA 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing in a [compound trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020), but I would think the best way to do this would be to just tweak your delete statement. If you wanted to delete the (1,2) relationship, you'd do:

```
delete from relateddocuments
  where ( from = 1 and to = 2 )
     or ( from = 2 and to = 1 );
```

This is where writing stored procedures to handle your SQL really helps.

Comment: It also seems that there should be a (hopefully very simple) way to tweak the queries (or post-processing in application space) to avoid having to store the back-links in the first place.

Comment: The catch is that I'd like to use the Java object mappings of JPA, i.e. like ``Document.getRelatedDocuments()`` and those don't work with "or" queries, only PK/FK relationships.

Comment: @eaolson: I'm intrigued by compound triggers, but a bit worried by what the documentation says here: "If, after the compound trigger fires, the triggering statement rolls back due to a DML exception: ... Side effects from firing the compound trigger are not rolled back." This is probably not a problem in my use case, but a bit scary nonetheless.